# Add the content of a TextField to a list with listener

Tags: java, javafx

I wrote a little JavaFX application that illustrates my problem. I have a set of checkBoxes and a TextField, all wrapped up in a Vbox which is constructed as the application starts. I would like that the checkBoxes which are checked get added to a list, which I managed to do, but for the TextField I don't get it.When I type text in the text field, all characters are added in the list, but I want the whole text added at once.
Here is my code to illustrate what I mean.

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    public VBox mainVb;
    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> checked = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        categories();
    }

    public void categories() {
        categories.add("Condition 1");
        categories.add("Condition 2");
        categories.add("Condition 3");
        categories.add("Condition 4");
        categories.add("Condition 5");
        categories.add("Condition 6");
        categories.add("Condition 7");
        categories.add("Condition 8");
        checked.add("Condition 2");
        checked.add("Condition 3");
        checked.add("Condition 6");

        for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++) {
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.setText(categories.get(i));
            if (checked.contains(categories.get(i))) checkBox.setSelected(true);
            checkBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    if (checkBox.isSelected()) checked.add(checkBox.getText());
                    if (!checkBox.isSelected()) checked.remove(checkBox.getText());
                }
            });
            mainVb.getChildren().add(checkBox);
        }
        TextField textArea = new TextField();
        textArea.setPromptText("Other...");
        textArea.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                checked.add(textArea.getText());
            }
        });
        mainVb.getChildren().add(textArea);
    }

    public void seeChecked(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(checked);
    }
}
```

If I enter "hello" in the TextField, it adds "h" "he" "hel" "hell" "hello" in my list. How do I make add "hello" at once.

Thank you very much.
Pierre.

Comment: That's the nature of the 'changed' event. Anything typed or deleted within the TextField fires this event. What you might want to try is a keyPress event and pick up on when the enter key is hit indicating the end of data entry into the TextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using setOnAction instead of the textProperty changed

```
 textArea.setOnAction(e ->  checked.add(textArea.getText()));
```

press enter in the TextField when done typing "hello"